# jQuery show div with same number suffix as first child of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First off I'd like to apologise for asking about something so specific but it's been wracking my brain all day and I'm out of ideas.

I'm using jquery to show and hide elements based on their number suffix ie:

`<a href="javascript:showCont(1)" class="tab"><span></span></a>` will target ->

`<div class="content" id="cont-1">This is content</div>` and it's working perfectly. I'd like to target another element based on the suffix of another element but I'm failing to. Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:showCont(1)" class="tab" id="tab-1">1</a>
<a href="javascript:showCont(2)" class="tab" id="tab-2">2</a>
<a href="javascript:showCont(3)" class="tab" id="tab-3">3</a>

<div class="content" id="cont-1"><p>This is content</p></div>
<div class="content" id="cont-2"><p>This is content</p></div>

<div class="content" id="cont-3">
    <div class="child" id="child-11"><p>This is the first child</p></div>
    <div class="child" id="child-12"><p>This is the second child</p></div>
</div>

<div class="external" id="external-11"><p>I am the first external</p></div>
<div class="external" id="external-12"><p>I am the second external</p></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.content .child:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
});

function showCont(num){
  $('.content').fadeOut(300);
  if(  $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none' ){
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();
  }else{
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
  }  
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    background:green;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
 }

.external{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}

.content, .external, .child{
  display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

**CodePen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uFpzE

**What I'm trying to achieve is this:**

If you click on `#tab-3` the `.external` div that corresponds with the first child of `#cont-3` should show.

I've tried this:

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content .child:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
 var random = $('#cont'+num + '.child:first-child').attr('id').replace(/child-/, ''); 
});

function showCont(num){
  $('.content').fadeOut(300);
  if( $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none'){
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();
    $('#external'+random).fadeIn({'duration':600,'queue':false});
  }else{
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
  }  
}
```

...and it isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possibly useful jquery function (not to fix your issue, just as a heads up): http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with the code in the `document.ready` part, but the `showCont` function does what you requested.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content .child:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
});

function showCont(num)
{
    $('.content').fadeOut(300);
    $('.external').fadeOut(300);

    if( $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none' )
    {
        $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();

        // get the child element's id
        var targetID = $("#cont-"+num).children().first().attr('id');

        if(targetID)
        {
            // construct the id of the external element
            $('#external-'+targetID.substring(targetID.indexOf('-')+1))
                .fadeIn({'duration':600,'queue':false});
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F2S4F/)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to make your preferred solution (doesn't have to be mine if you like another one better) as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got `random` in the wrong function. The `#cont` and `#external` selectors are also missing a trailing dash:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content .child:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
});

function showCont(num){
  var random = $('#cont-'+num + '.child:first-child').attr('id').replace(/child-/, ''); 
  $('.content').fadeOut(300);
  if( $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none'){
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();
    $('#external-'+random).fadeIn({'duration':600,'queue':false});
  }else{
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
  }  
}
```

This should be closer to what you're after (untested though).

Once you've got it working, you could look at simplifying it by using `data-id="num"` attributes on your HTML elements and accessing the id values with `.data('id')` in your js, then binding the tab buttons from within your DOM ready fn. It would look closer to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tab').click(function (e) {
        var num = $(this).data('id'),
            $child = $('.child[data-id="' + num + '"]')
        ;
        // ...
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable random is not defined in your JS file, and there are some typos regarding the selector elements (e.g. it should be $('#external-'+random) instead of $('#external'+random)). Base on your code, I came up with the following for your reference:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FjoBI)

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.content .child:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
});

function showCont(num){
  $('.content').fadeOut(300);
if( $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none' )
  {
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();
    var random = $('#cont-'+num + ' div:first-child').attr('id').substring(6);
    $('#external-'+random).fadeIn({'duration':600,'queue':false});
  }
 else
  {
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
    var random = $('#cont-'+num + ' div:first-child').attr('id').substring(6);
    $('#external-'+random).fadeOut({'duration':600,'queue':false});
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this changes to your `function showCont(num)` would do:

```
 $('.content').fadeOut(300);
    if(  $('#cont-'+num).css('display')=='none' )
    {
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeIn();
    var value= $('#cont-'+num+' div' ).first().attr("id").slice(-2);
    $('#external-'+value).fadeIn();
  }
  else
    {
    $('#cont-'+num).fadeOut();
    $('.external').fadeOut();
  }
```